# Periodic groups: subgroups and quotients

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups, free-abelian-group

Let $(G,+)$ a finely generated abelian group. My problem is to prove that $G$ is direct sum of cyclic subgroups, each of which is infinite, or has order the potency of a prime number.

Suppose that $G$ is not a periodic group, and let $G=<x_1,...,x_t>$. We proceed by induction $t$, for $t=1$ the assertion is obvious. Let $t>1$, and consider

$$H:=\lbrace x \in G : mx \in <x_1>, m \in \mathbb{N} \rbrace$$

$H \leq G$, $x_1 \in H$, and $H$ is not periodic (because $G$ is not periodic? is it correct?). Now $G/H$ is $(t-1)$-generated (why is it $(t-1)$-generated?)
and $G$ not periodic implies also that $G/H$ is not periodic in the sense that $G/H$ defines a partition of $G$? In particular, by inductive hypothesis, $G/H$ is free abelian group, i.e. there is $K \leq G$ such that $G=H \bigoplus K$.

$H/<x_1>$ is finely generated and periodc group (why is it finely generated and periodic?), and by another result is finite, let $card(H/<x_1>)=n$, and consider the following homomorphism

$$\varphi: h \in H \longrightarrow nh \in <x_1>$$

$H$ not periodic implies that Ker$(\varphi)=\lbrace 0 \rbrace$ and $H$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $<x_1>$, and then $H$ is infinite cyclic (why $H$ is infinite?).

My doubts are during the demonstration, thanks for every reply.

Comment: You need to pick $x_1$ an element of infinite order (otherwise $H$ is periodic) and conclude the last line that $H$ is infinite cyclic for being subgroup of an infinite cyclic. However, I'm not entirely sure this will also answer all the other questions.

Comment: As an answer, do you want a solution of the problem, i.e. a proof of the theorem you're mentioning, or do you want answers to the questions in the middle of your "proof" and corrections to your proof ?

Comment: @Max In my notes that is this the "proof", and clearly I did not understand it, I would like to have the answers to my questions.

Comment: Ok. By "not periodic", do you mean torsion-free, i.e. $n\cdot y= 0 \implies y= 0$ ?

Comment: @Max $x \in G$ not periodic mean that $<x>$ has infinite order, a gruop $G$ is not periodic if each $x \in G$ is not periodic.

Comment: @spynes Just a remark, the usual definition of periodic (torsion) is every element has finite order, so, non periodic groups contain at least one infinite order element, different from torsion-free groups.

Comment: No @GilbertoLópez , "not if there is at least one", $G$ is not periodic if each element of $G \setminus \lbrace 0_g \rbrace$ is not periodic. The definition of $G$ not periodic is not negation of $G$ periodic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$H$ is not periodic, because it is a subgroup of an aperiodic group, you are right there. 
$G/H$ is $(t-1)$-generated, because clearly $x_1 \in H$, and so the classes of $x_2,...,x_t$ mod $\langle x_1 \rangle$ generate $G/H$.

$G/H$ is not periodic, because if $n\cdot (y+ H) = 0$, then $n\cdot y \in H$, which implies that there exists $m$ such that $mn\cdot y \in \langle x_1 \rangle$, which in turn, by definition, implies $y\in H$, which implies $y+ H = H$, which is the zero of $G/H$.

The argument as to why there exists $K$ such that $K\oplus H = G$ is not very clear. I think one way to see it is to do it is using Zorn's lemma, but I'm not sure it's what your teacher meant.

$H/\langle x_1\rangle$ is periodic because if $y\in H$ then for some $m$, $m\cdot y \in \langle x_1\rangle$, that is $m\cdot (y+\langle x_1 \rangle) = 0$ mod $\langle x_1\rangle$. It is finitely generated because $H$ is.

$H$ is infinite because it is not perdiodic (a finite group is periodic)

Comment: The argument not clear is another Lemma:"If G is abelian group and $H \leq G$ such that $G/H$ is free-abelian (by definition is direct sum of cyclic infinite subgroups), then $H$ is a direct addition of $G$, i.e. there is $K\leq G$ such that $G=H \bigoplus K$. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Ok well that explains it.